# jqgrid show the images in popup box

Tags: jqgrid, prettyphoto

I am using the jqgrid, and prettyphoto in my application.
I have a column to show the image preview. on clicking that image is the image will be displayed in the popup box.
grid code is..

```
.....  
{name: 'imagePath', index: 'imagePath', width: 80, align: 'center',
    formatter :anchorFmatter, edittype: 'text', hidden: false, editable: true,
    editrules: {required: false}, editoptions: {size: 30}}
....
function anchorFmatter(cellValue, options, rowObject)
{
    if(cellValue === null ){
        return "<a></a>";
    }else {
        jQuery("a[rel='image']").prettyPhoto({
            animation_speed:'normal',
            show_title:false,
            allow_resize:true,
            default_width:640,
            default_height:385,
            theme:'light_rounded',
            autoplay:false
        });

        return "<a href='" + cellValue + "' rel='image'><img src='" + cellValue +
               "' width='100' height='35'></a>";
    }
}
```

all images in the grid are coming in popup, but the last image is coming in new browser page.
may get any help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) the grid contain exist still as string and not yet placed on the page. So you should remove the calls `jQuery("a[rel='image']").prettyPhoto` from the formutter function. Instead of that you can call the `jQuery("a[rel='image']").prettyPhoto` inside of [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events) event handler. Additionally you should use `gridview:true` option if you not already use it. It will improve the grid performance.

Comment: Thank you very much Oleg. It was worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hai @Oleg, I am facing new problem. while I am testing the application in IE6 the Image is coming in new window.(not coming in popup box). Can you please help me to find a way to solve this?

Comment: @vissu pepala: It looks like IE6 compatibility problem of `prettyPhoto` plugin. Is there are the same problem if you don't use `prettyPhoto` inside of jqGrid?

Comment: Sorry for late response, This is the problem of IE6 compatibility of prettyPhoto plugin only. and Working fine in IE8. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @vissu pepala: Sorry, but I don't use `prettyPhoto` myself, so I can't help you in the subject. Moreover I think that IE6 is so old and so seldom be used that you should just not support it.